# java vs python for GAE

Tags: java, python, performance, google-app-engine, web-frameworks

from these links:-

```
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=java    
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=java
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=java 
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=java
```

they appear clearly that the best choice for GAE is java, if scalable feature is what we are looking for.

my question is, What are the implications that will affect on performance if we use one of frameworks?

e.g.

```
 django     --> python
 spring MVC --> java
 slim3      --> java
 ... etc
```

Comment: unless you have keep alive, your app goes to sleep when there is no activity for a period of time. this makes spring mvc a bit troublesome since it requires a long startup.

Comment: there are lies, damn lies and benchmarks ...

Comment: "After all, **facts are facts**, and although we may quote one to another with a chuckle the words of the Wise Statesman, *Lies--damned lies--and statistics*, still there are [some easy figures the simplest must understand, and the astutest cannot wriggle out of](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/)."
Leonard Henry Courtney, 1895

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick note - don't take this as a definitive/comprehensive comparison:

Both Django and Spring have a long startup time, which can lead to requests being dropped. I'd go with a framework that was speciffically made for GAE: tipify, slim3, etc..

Comment: I'm a big fan of Tipfy. I believe it comes out the fastest in most Python App Engine framework comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

I'm used both Python and Java on GAE, one project done using Python+Django, and one using Java/Groovy+Spring.

Python+Django is very easy to develop, initially, but not so easy to maintain. It have enough fast startup time, good documentation, atc.

Java+Spring requires more development (some parts takes 2-3 times more than doing same using django), have problems with startup time (even if you are using `warmup` requests). But it much more stable.

Python project have too much errors, mostly without any visible (to you) reason :( And it's very hard to find cause of this errors, because of dynamic nature of lang. And also, be ready to manually patch some libraries you're using. Don't get me wrong, i have many years of Python experience, but it's really hard to maintain it on such distributed systems like GAE, and it's really have problems with quality of code :(

Java, in other hand, works very well. In case when your code have problems, you'll see all information you need to fix this, and after few iterations you'll fix almost all bugs. Except one: sometimes you'll see startup errors :( Not too often, btw

PS btw, choosing right language for GAE depend on what language you knows betters :) If you don't know Java yet - don't start with it, it requires at least 1-2 years to understand language.

Answer (score 2):

These benchmarks compare Python 3 to Java on a (presumably) standard setup. There's no indication of what sort of workload these benchmarks test, either.

App Engine runs Python 2.5, in a decidedly different configuration to what you'd find on a standard desktop, so the benchmarks really don't apply.

Further, scalability isn't about benchmarks like these - they make, at most, a constant factor difference. If your app is built to scale, it will scale in either language, to the same degree. Scalability depends on how well you architect your app and use the underlying infrastructure.

I would recommend using whatever language and framework you're most comfortable with - don't pick your language based on benchmarks.

Comment: >>(presumably) standard setup<< Did you read the Help page?

Comment: >>no indication of what sort of workload these benchmarks test<< Did you read any other page on the website?

Comment: @igouy It really is totally irrelevant, because my point remains: The benchmarks aren't on App Engine, or any setup that approximates App Engine, and they're not using the same version of Python, either.

Comment: of course, benchmarks are not on app engine. but you will pay to GAE what you consume of CPU time, memory .. etc which all computing systems depend on.

Comment: @Nick Johnson - You guessed but did not know those measurements were not for App Engine. You were plain wrong to say - "There's no indication of what sort of workload these benchmarks test". You're correct to suggest we should always check the systems we intend to use - rather than gamble that they will perform just like some other arbitrary machine.

Comment: @igouy I did not guess: Python 3 does not run on App Engine, and I know the benchmarking site does not run on App Engine.